# matlab gui popup menu error message

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created a GUI and there is a pop-up menu in it. I want to know how I can generate an error dialogue when the pop-up menu is not open/used by a user. For the edit box, I use "isempty", but that doesn't work for the pop-up menu.
if the user don't open the pop-up menu and don't select any choice from this pop-up menu i want my program display an error message for remind the user select a choice.

Thanks and I look forward to hearing your solution

Comment: Are you asking how to trap the error, or how to generate the error message? If it's the latter, use `errordlg`.

Comment: if the user don't open the pop-up menu and don't select any choice from this pop-up menu i want my program display an error message for remind the user select a choice.

Comment: You haven't answer my question. Are you asking how to check if the user didn't open the pop-up menu, or how to display an error dialog box?

Comment: How to display an error dialog box if the user didn't open the pop-up menu.

Comment: For the third time, what you are asking is unclear, because it involves doing two separate steps: 1. Detect an event that the user didn't open your pop-up menu, and 2. If such event is detected, show a error dialog box. What is it that you don't know how to do? Is it step 1, step 2, or is it both?

Comment: the step 1. i want detect an event that the user didn't open my pop-up menu. i hope explain you correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    val=get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value');
        switch val
                case 1, errordlg('invalid option');
                case 2, disp('option 1 selected'); %SEE COMMAND WINDOW
                case 3, disp('option 2 selected'); %SEE COMMAND WINDOW
        end
```

(to be clearer)
set the first string of the popup menu to something like "choose an option"; that string has value 1 and is displayed in the popup when you start the gui. if the user do not change the selection of the popup or re-selects it, the error occurs.

Comment: if you create a new blank gui and add a popup menu and a pushbutton, enter 3 strings in the popup String property (using property inspector), save the gui and make the pushbutton callback as the one i posted, it will work.. let me know

Comment: i try this code but i have the same problem because at the case 1 i have a selection which i need. Your code if the user doesn't open the popup menu display the error msg but the same msg displayed when i select the first select at the case 1. My program have 50 popup menu and for solve the problem must change all the case 1 to all the popup menu. Maybe don't have other solution. Thank you for your time!!!!

Comment: @user2262401 If you think the case 1 as a sentence that explains what the popup allows to do, then you should agree that if case 1 is selected the error must occur, that is equal to the case in which the user doesn't touch the popup, your first important case is case 2, your real first option. You will figure it out, nevermind. Hope you find your solution.